# How to get output from ExecDos::exec

Tags: installation, nsis, netstat

When I execute `netstat -a |find /C $portNumber` in command prompt I get the total number of lines where the given port number exists.

I want to get that same count in any variable so that I can check whether the port is already occupied or free in NSIS.

I am excuting the below command and I tried in many ways, but I'm not able to get the output of the ExecDos::exec in a variable or in the stack.

```
ExecDos::exec "netstat -a |find /C '$portNumber'| $output"
```

Comment: ... | $output is not a valid way to capture output unless $output expands to " > myfile.txt" etc. The execute plugins that support capturing stdout have specil syntax for it, check the plugin documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To enable shell behavior you have to execute `cmd.exe /C yourcommand` (Or expand %ComSpec% with `ExpandEnvStrings` but hardcoding cmd.exe is ok if you don't support Win9x)

Or you can try the [ExecCmd plug-in](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ExecCmd_plug-in) which does this for you (But it has fewer options so you would have to redirect the output to a file)

`nsExec::ExecToStack` with the cmd prefix should also work...

**Edit:**

Here is a working example (I used nsExec since it part of the default install)

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
section
ExpandEnvStrings $0 %COMSPEC%
StrCpy $1 445 ;Port number
nsExec::ExecToStack '"$0" /C netstat -an|find /C ":$1"'
Pop $0
${If} $0 = 0
    Pop $0
    MessageBox mb_ok "Port count=$0"
${Else}
    ; Port not open...
${EndIf}
sectionend
```

Comment: I am writing this code for NSIS windows Installer. Context is I need to check whether the given port is free or not (not used by any application)  So thought of using netstat -a and find the port in the result of netstat command.

Comment: Can anyone please tel me how to check whether the port is binded to other application or not in my .nsi file.  Help is highly appreciated!!

Comment: I am really waiting for a help. Please throw me some light

Comment: Did you try any of the things I suggested?

Comment: I am getting invalid command error for this line  `code` nsExec::ExecToStack '"$0" /C netstat -an|find /C ":$1"'

Comment: What is the exact compiler error? Did you install NSIS with the default plugins? (The installed plugins are listed early in the compiler output)

Comment: thank u for the help.  I am getting compiler error like this **Invalid command: nsExec::ExecToStack **  for this code. `nsExec::ExecToStack '"$0" /C netstat -an|find /C ":$1"'`  Should i include any plugin?

Comment: That plugin should be part of the default install, try re-installing NSIS and make sure that plugin is checked on the components page...

Comment: can u pls tel me which dll represents nsExec? or is there any other option of achieving ur code using ExecDos ?

Comment: which version of NSIS is the latest one?

Comment: 2.46 (How hard is it to just check the website?)

Comment: sorry, I just reinstalled and now its getting compiled and now verifying the port status

Comment: thank u so much for the solution. I am really thankful to u. IS this way of port availability check is efficient?  because when i do netstat - an in my command prompt, it also shows the foreign address port binding. if port is used at foreign address also this says port is not free. Could u pls comment on this.  thank u once again!!

Comment: A) Compare with the result of "netstat -n" B) Use something like netstat -an|find /V "ESTAB"|find /V "ACK"|find /C ":135"  C) You would have to stop using the /C find switch and parse each returned line after pop'ing it